# 2 node bots into one?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i am looking to have 2 node discord bots into one. would there be an easier way to do it then this post?
[Running different discord.js bot instances in the same NodeJS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61074606/running-different-discord-js-bot-instances-in-the-same-nodejs-project)
i have tried that way and it works. though i needed to copy and paste my code again adding the new bot to the spots where it says botname.on to activate it there.
in summary i need it to do this a easier way to not make it so long and needing to copy paste code so much

Comment: I dont't think that there's an easier way to do this

Comment: You have to catch the events from each bot individually. But you can use the same handler function for them.

Comment: @nulldev can you clarify?

Comment: `client1.on("foo", handleFoo); client2.on("foo", handleFoo);` -> two events, one handler function for both. Ill formulate an answer once I get home.